# How to remove NZEC Runtime Error (Python)?

Tags: python, runtime-error, eof

Problem link https://www.codechef.com/problems/TREE2

why is this code not running on CodeChef, throwing Runtime Error: NZEC ?
This will run over HackerRank right?

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    l=set(map(int,input().strip().split()))
    print(len(l))
```

Comment: There is no NZEC error. In codechef, you need to check custom input and add the input data CodeChef does not assume input data based on problem automatically. You dont need input data on pressing submit. but you do need it when pressing run

Comment: when I put custom Input, its giving me the output I want, but when I submit none of the test cases are passing. Why so?

Check the Question in the link please.

Comment: Maybe because you only considered one test case and it is passing that but your logic is not right, so other test cases are failing.

Comment: I do solve this kind of codes in HR, this would have ran there. Can you help me by sending a Code how you would have solved that question?